# Modal popup on window close using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website where the customers come and purchase any product. But there are some customers who closes the tab without doing any purchase. I don't want to lose those customers. So `i have decided to provide offers for those customers in the "modal" popup. This popup has to be displayed once the customer clicks the close button in the browser`. This `popup will have a form` to select the offers, fill their contact details and submit the form. Once the form gets submitted, the window can be closed automatically. Is it possible to provide such a popup modal. I have surfed regarding this. Everyone says about the `onbeforeunload` with `confirm` and `alert` box. Could anyone help me on this.

Comment: That sounds intrusive, you may discourage some people from revisiting let alone buy anything.

Comment: @zer00ne Got your point. The customers can also close the window once the popup appears. Just providing them an offer which will be useful for both the sides. Im not forcing the customer to do something strictly. Just providing the chance with some offers.

Comment: Ah, ok that sounds ok, many sites do that, it's still a little irritating but not intrusive. Can you provide any code, sir?

Comment: @zer00ne This is my business logic. I have tried it inside onbeforeunload function. I think that won't work. I don't know much about this. I don't have any code to provide. Sorry

Comment: That would leave me to do a guessing game that's not very productive, good luck to you, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done. That is after the user has clicked on close there is no way to do it.
But I think what you are looking for is what is called a 'Exit intent popup'.
The idea is simple: you use js/jquery to find if the user is 'about to' close the page(say from mouse movements and such) and display the said popup.
Here is one such plugin : [BIOEP](http://beeker.io/exit-intent-popup-script-tutorial)

You can just google 'Exit intent popups' for many more.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it from your page code,
only place I see this is in extensions.